# What is wrong with this MySQL Query (PHP)?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

So I have this small section of code that for some reason doesn't want to actually work. I have been trying to figure out why, and to no avail.

```
$mysqli =& db::connect();

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `my_table`";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
if( ! $result ) die( "SQL Error ($mysqli->errno): $mysqli->error" );
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
//Do something here
}
```

I get the following error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object in

When trying to run that script.

Any suggestions?

Edit: More information if necessary:
There are 174 records in the table I am trying to query.
Running PHP 5.3 and MySQL 5.1.
I can run the same query in phpMyAdmin with no issues.

Edit 2: Yes that is the full query. Here is the result of a var_dump:

```
object(mysqli_result)#2 (5) { 
    ["current_field"]=> int(0) 
    ["field_count"]=> int(16) 
    ["lengths"]=> NULL 
    ["num_rows"]=> int(174) 
    ["type"]=> int(0) 
}
```

Edit 3:
Snipping this as it is not useful at all.

Edit 4:

I can't seem to find any information on why a mysqli_result object cannot be used in a while loop. Every answer I find ends up going back to "Make sure you have a mysqli_result", which I most certainly do as can be seen from the above var_dump. I will have to come back to this a bit later, but any suggestions would be great.

Edit 5:

Thanks to @Quassnoi for the headsup on checking for secondary assignment on the $result variable. This was the case during the execution of the loop, as I had a conditional statement that would do a check of another portion of the database, but only on certain conditions. I should probably just stick to prepared statements for little conditional checks like that.

Comment: Is that the *actual* query? Please post the real SQL if it isn't.

Comment: Do `var_dump($result)` to see what `$result` is before the while loop.

Comment: Additionally, if I put a `$row = $result->fetch_assoc(); var_dump($row);` before the while loop, it fetches and dumps a single row. This literally makes no sense to me whatsoever.

Comment: Please post the contents of "do something". I think you're assigning some value to `$result` inside it.

Comment: does the procedural style for `fetch_assoc` differ in anyway? (http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php - example #2)

Comment: Are you sure that is the line generating the error? i.e., did you check the line number and are you calling fetch_assoc() anywhere else ...

Comment: Does `$result = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM my_table")` work?

Comment: Also, if it's a large amt of data you're retrieving, you might want to consider adding the param `MYSQLI_USE_RESULT` after your query in the `->query()` call.